# Azure DevOps project - Service Fabric deploy - sample failing

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric

I have created a new Azure DevOps project. Asp.Net core 2.1, Service Fabric deploy.

First deploy went fine. Without any changes subsequent releases are failing

warnings and error

```
2018-10-10T08:24:17.8368242Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy Service Fabric Application
2018-10-10T08:24:17.8375072Z ==============================================================================
2018-10-10T08:24:17.8375163Z Task         : Service Fabric Application Deployment
2018-10-10T08:24:17.8375234Z Description  : Deploy a Service Fabric application to a cluster.
2018-10-10T08:24:17.8375288Z Version      : 1.7.22
2018-10-10T08:24:17.8375356Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-10-10T08:24:17.8375410Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=820528)
2018-10-10T08:24:17.8375479Z ==============================================================================
2018-10-10T08:24:20.0073284Z Searching for path: D:\a\r1\a\**\drop\projectartifacts\**\PublishProfiles\Cloud.xml
2018-10-10T08:24:20.2879096Z Found path: D:\a\r1\a\Drop\drop\projectartifacts\Application\Voting\PublishProfiles\Cloud.xml
2018-10-10T08:24:20.3657104Z Searching for path: D:\a\r1\a\**\drop\applicationpackage
2018-10-10T08:24:20.4618957Z Found path: D:\a\r1\a\Drop\drop\applicationpackage
2018-10-10T08:24:20.7317155Z Imported cluster client certificate with thumbprint '25826D862588CBFA3D2113D882255156F7233F44'.
2018-10-10T08:25:02.0637557Z ##[warning]Failed to contact Naming Service. Attempting to contact Failover Manager Service...
2018-10-10T08:25:42.0730582Z ##[warning]Failed to contact Failover Manager Service, Attempting to contact FMM...
2018-10-10T08:26:22.0962942Z ##[warning]No such host is known
2018-10-10T08:26:22.2408731Z Service fabric SDK version: 3.2.176.9494.
2018-10-10T08:26:22.4279087Z ##[error]No cluster endpoint is reachable, please check if there is connectivity/firewall/DNS issue.
2018-10-10T08:26:22.4687237Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Service Fabric Application
```

All other devops project releases are failing also for same reason.

Any help to debug appreciated

Comment: it is very likely that your cluster is down, inaccessible or the configuration file is wrong

Answer (score 0):

well, this clearly has nothing to do with the release if all the releases are failing. Something happened to your cluster or to your service endpoint

You would need to check if you can connect to the cluster endpoint manually with powershell, for example (connect-servicefabricluster or something along those lines).

Comment: cluster is being deployed as part of the release so no cluster. using the service fabric deploy task. edited q to include complete log

Answer (score 0):

misunderstanding of built in release task.
guess cluster was created by DevOps project create and not release task as I thought.